# WebRTC support in popular desktop browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, microsoft-edge

Searching Internet I can't find information in common place of the current WebRTC and related technologies support status in popular desktop browsers.
Probably, I am doing it wrong.

What is the support status of WebRTC in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge in terms of:

1. Audio codecs
2. Video codecs
3. Signalling protocols

?

Or do you know Web page which summarizes information above?

Comment: [This](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc) and [this](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/) might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, Edge does not support WebRTC. However, WebRTC and ORTC are mainly compatible on the wire.

1. Audio Codec
   Opus is mandatory to implement, and supported by all browsers.
   G.711 is supported by all browsers.
   G.722 is supported by Edge and Chrome (not Firefox).
   Edge also supports SILK.
   Chrome also supports iSAC and iLBC.
2. Video Codec
   VP8 and H264 both mandatory to implement. Firefox supports both today. Chrome supports VP8, supports H.264 on iOS and Android, and should support H.264 in all version starting from M49.
   Additionally, chrome supports VP9.
   Today, Edge supports only their own version of H.264 SVC they call H264UC. Bernard Aboba, the main architect from MS, mentioned they will support H.264 and VP9 soon.
3. Signalling protocol
    This is not defined in webRTC, so this is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this on this website for instance : https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webrtcwebrtcv10api?filter=f3f0000bf&search=webrtc

And I this you would like to know more about this : http://rtc.works which helps you get support of webRTC everywhere.

Hope this helps. :)